# html TD full width overlap others

Tags: html, css

As you can see on jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/8khjK/1/, the TD is not actually full width. I would like it to be something like:

```
text A                      text B        
text A                      text B       
text A                      text B       
----------------------------------
|           ONLY 1 TD            |
----------------------------------
text A                      text B
```

Is it possible with `td` or do I need to look for other approachs like create another table?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

add colspan:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>text A</td>
        <td>text B</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>text A</td>
        <td>text B</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>text A</td>
        <td>text B</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2" style=' background-color: #ccc'> Only 1 TD!!!!</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>text A</td>
        <td>text B</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

FIDDLE:
http://jsfiddle.net/8khjK/2/

Answer (score 2):

You should use colspan attribute of that td because you want it to have 2 columns space:

```
<td colspan="2" ...></td>
```